# Multiple object with same animation but different values in React with gsap

Tags: reactjs, animation, gsap

Basically I want multiple objects to move up from the bottom, from random position on the X axis.

So there are some common properties and some other which I want to be random for every single object:

```js
const objectFrom = {
  bottom: 0,
  left: /* random between 5-100 */
}
```

What would be better approach than defining a lot of refs, a lot of `<div />`'s like:

```js
  const object1 = useRef();
  //...
  const object10 = useRef();
```

And:

```html
  <div className="object1" ref={object1}/>
  // ...
  <div className="object10" ref={object10}/>
```

Then animate all that objects one by one in timeline in `useEffect`:

```js
  timeline.fromTo(object1.current, {...objectFrom, left: `${gsap.utils.random(5, 100)}%`,}, objectTo, '<');
  //...
  timeline.fromTo(object10.current, {...objectFrom, left: `${gsap.utils.random(5, 100)}%`,}, objectTo, '<');
```

And the problem that I have with that is that `random()` function is not generating a random value for every single object. There is one random value but for all of the objects.

Second problem this just looks horrible.

How to achieve this goal with the best approach?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet with your full script?

Comment: I don't understand.. What you wanna see? All this code, refs, and timelines but just multiplicated by how many of them I need?

Comment: You don't have to show all of your code, just enough to make a demo version.